# can i submit a form without submit button or without hitting enter?

Tags: php, html

Can I submit value of `<select>` in php form without having submit button?
  In my html/php code I am using two form or we can say two `<select>` as you can see in  coding. In the second `<select>`(sub category) I want to use value of first `<select>`(main category) so that it can show me sub category of main `<select>`. but I am getting confused, how to do this on a single page without using js.

See my code:

```
<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
main course name <select name ="bcate" ><option value=''>choose</option><?php $auth->cmaster_array(); ?></select>
</form>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
sub course name <select name ="sbcate" ><option value=''>select sub course</option><?php $auth->clmaster_array($frsbct); ?></select>
section name <input type="text" name="cname" required/>
remarks <input type="text" name="remarks" required/> 
<input type="submit" name="section_master" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like the XY problem. Of course you can send a form without button, by using javascript. But looks more like you just want a conditional select, which is not achieved by sending the form, but only the `<select>` value with AJAX and then populate the next `<select>` with the AJAX response

Comment: This cannot be done without AJAX or page refresh. Even if you submit the 1st form, how are you planning to fetch the values for 2nd form? Note: _The PHP of the 2nd form will have finished executing before the user selects an option in the 1st form_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you've asked that , You need value of first select input for second input values.

You can do this only by using jQuery without submitting form.

write change event of first select input box.

then send data to your server by jQuery ajax.

and then fill the second input box received from ajax

Code :

```
// To get value of select box

$('#select_box_id').change(function() 
{
        var select_box_one_value = $(this).val();
});

$.ajax
({
       type: "POST",
       url: HOST + "/path/to_your_controller_function",
       data: 'data_of_select_box='+select_box_one_value,
       cache: false,
       success: function(msg)
       {
       }
});
```

using this , your controller will get the value of select box value and then return data from there , and you will receive that data in `msg` variable.

Comment: can you please explain it more .

Comment: i tried change event, its working little bit but i dnt knw how to pass value ... how can i show u my code now ... can i paste here ??

Comment: done its working . if u dnt mind how can i catch u again to ask direct question .. is thr any msg service on stakeoverflow ???

Comment: Great.. Enjoy.. I am not aware about any message service.

Comment: ok, so here can u please tell me why why two datepicker are not working in my html form (only in ie) .. even i m using 2 diffrent id's for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form using javascript.
You can use this code to submit the form

```
document.getElementById("[ur form id should be here]").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
<form id="jsform" action="whatever you want">
// input fields
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('jsform').submit();
</script>
```